# How do i take a specific node and turn it into a block

Tags: nodes, blocks

I created a content type of which there is only one node of, and i want to add to sidebar left. How can that be done? i would prefer not have to use a module to do this., thanks

Comment: i just tried this, did 'Add Block' and added some PHP that echoed out what i wanted but it printed the PHP. surely there's a way to do this.

Comment: i'm just going to hardwire it to the page.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) for this.

1. Create a "Content" view and choose your content type in the "Show" dropdown
2. Uncheck "Create a page" and check "Create a block"
3. Choose "Unformatted list" and "Full posts"
4. Limit the block to 1 "items per page"
5. Click the Continue & Edit button
6. Add a contextual filter for Content: NID
7. Provide a default argument of Fixed value and enter the Node ID of the node you want to display within the block

*Optionally, you can choose to create a fields based view instead of full posts which would allow you a little more control over the layout of the nodes content within the block.*

If you are set on not using ANY modules to do this then you'll want to look into https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7 which would allow you to override a blocks output in your themes template.php.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter().
 */
function YOURTHEME_block_view_block_BLOCKDELTA_alter(&$data, $block) {
  $data['content'] = drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Node Block](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock). I know it's a module and you didn't want to use one, but it's lightweight and will probably do exactly what you want.